# Unity 3D Admob SDK Update

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, admob

Admob sent me an e-mail.
On how to update to version 7.0.0 of the Google mobile ads SDK.
But I do not fully understand how to update.
Unity google mobile ads plugin and google play services are not working together.
The latest version of Unity google mobile ads plugin is enough for advertising.

What I want to ask;
I would like to update to google mobile ads SDK 7.0.0 in unity application.
If you import only Google Mobile Ads Plugin v7.0.1 into the app, AdMob will accept it.
Because the new Unity google mobile ads plugin and google play services do not work together.